# Perl implementation of the GNU Coreutils

Tags: perl, gnu-coreutils

I want to learn Perl and thought that the most of GNU Coreutils seems to be doing stuff which are well suited for the language. Is there any Perl implementation of it (at least the basic functionality) which I could look at for comparison?

In my experience, looking at code is the second best way to learn a language (after writing code). I'm interested both in quick-and-dirty implementations and clean code which covers edge cases as well.

For example, `cat` could be implemented as

```
alias cat='perl -Tpe "" --'
```

although there are some [edge cases](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=258980) where it doesn't behave the same. And of course it ignores all flags.

Comment: There is a shell http://gnp.github.io/psh/

Comment: There is also a list of one-liners at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=627015. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has already been done years ago: http://search.cpan.org/dist/ppt/

Comment: It was much more complex than I expected. The cat implementation was 66 lines excluding comments and documentation.

Comment: And it still doesn't handle pipes in filenames correctly. Running `./ppt/bin/cat 'echo hello|'` gives
`Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at ./ppt/ppt/bin/cat line 59.`